# Add view to specific row and column in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-gridlayout

My final objective is to be able to drag a view and drop it into a grid-oriented layout (i.e. a layout that restricts the placement of these views to cells, instead of anywhere).

I'm trying to do that with `GridLayout`, as it seemed appropriate, but I am now doubting if it is possible to do what I want using it.

When handling the drop, I try to add views to the `GridLayout` as such:

```
            GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(4);
            GridLayout.Spec column = GridLayout.spec(2);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(gridLayout.getContext());
            gridLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null), new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, column));
```

The view does get added to the `GridLayout`, but not to the right cell (which would be, for the code above, the cell on the 5th row, 3rd column).

How can I do this correctly? Should I try something else besides `GridLayout`? `GridLayout` seemed appropriate because I also want to be able to place views with different sizes in it (i.e. views that would span more or less cells).

Thank you.

**Edit:**
I am considering using a `RelativeLayout` and adding views to it like so:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
params.leftMargin = 50;
params.topMargin = 60;
relativeLayout.addView(myView, params);
```

This way, I can specify the exact coordinates (e.g. `(50;60)`) of the view.

Comment: Is it possible to fill your `GridLayout` with an adapter? Then you could add and remove views by adding to and removing from your collection and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @KalaBalik Sorry, I don't understand how this solves the issue. How could I use an adapter to specify **where** in the grid the view would be positioned?

Comment: Your Adapter holds a collection and displays item views **in the order of the collection**.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see the api does not provide this functionality, but you can do the following:

you can set:

> mGridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);

or

> mGridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

to organize how the

> mGridLayout.addView(view)

adds the childs in the grid. Using the first method (default) the childs are filled by columns first, whereas the second by rows first